# EF Core “Invalid column name 'Discriminator'” error with inheritance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have the following entities:

```
public abstract class Freezer
{
    public int FreezerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int FreezerTypeId { get; set; }
    public int Capacity { get; set; }
}

public class FoodFreezer : Freezer
{
    public List<FoodItem> Foods { get; set; }
}

public class ChemicalFreezer : Freezer
{
    public List<ChemicalItem> Chemicals { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see the derived `Freezer` classes do not contain any data that would be stored in the database; they only contain a navigation property of the specific types of contents.

I have the following configurations:

```
internal class FreezerConfiguration<T> : DbEntityConfiguration<T> where T : Freezer
{
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<T> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Freezers");
        builder.HasKey(x => x.FreezerId);

        builder.Property(x => x.FreezerId).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(x => x.FreezerTypeId).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(x => x.Capacity).IsRequired();
    }
}

internal class FoodFreezerConfiguration : FreezerConfiguration<FoodFreezer>
{
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<FoodFreezer> builder)
    {
        builder.HasMany(x => x.FoodItems).WithOne(x => x.Freezer);
    }
}
```

When I make a call to get a list of `FoodFreezer`s from my context, I get a "Invalid column name 'Discriminator'" error.  After doing some research, it seems it doesn't like the fact that `FoodFreezer` and `ChemicalFreezer` point to a single table.  What do I need to change?  Do I need a FoodFreezers and ChemicalFreezers database tables with only a `FreezerId` column that's a FK to the Freezers table?

Comment: Seems like you want to achieve a Table-per-Hierarchy (TPH) structure, but you don't seem to use the `HasDiscriminator()` method in your mapping. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/inheritance

Answer (score 4):

@haim770 led me down the right path.  I had to add the following to my `FreezerConfiguration`:

```
builder.HasDiscriminator(x => x.FreezerTypeId)
    .HasValue<FoodFreezer>(FreezerTypeEnum.Food)
    .HasValue<ChemicalFreezer>(FreezerTypeEnum.Chemical);
```

No additional tables or code needed.  If I try to get a `FoodFreezer` using the ID of a `ChemicalFreezer`, it returns `null`.  Really cool.