# EF Core error invalid column "discriminator" with inheritance

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm new to EF Core and sorry if this is a stupid question.
I'm getting the Invalid Column "Discriminator" when I try to query

```
Context.EmployeeAddressNavigation.where(x =>x.Name.Contains("name")).Select(x => new {x.Id,x.employAddress})
```

**Employee**

```
public class Employee
{
   public Guid Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

**EmployeeAddress**

```
public class EmployeeAddress
{
  public Guid EmployeeId {get;set;}
  public Guid AddressId {get;set;}
}
```

**EmployeeAddressNavigation**

```
public class EmployeeAddressNavigation : Employee
{
   public EmpoyeeAddress employAddress {get;set;}
}
```

I configured onModelCreate like this

```
override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().ToTable("employee");
    modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeAddress>().ToTable("employeeaddress");
    modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeAddressNavigation>()
            .HasMany(r => r.EmployeeAddress)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(r => r.EmployeeId);
}
```

I saw similar question here [EF Core “Invalid column name 'Discriminator'” error with inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638929/ef-core-invalid-column-name-discriminator-error-with-inheritance) but I did not understand how to fix my issue ? Can some one please also explain me how to use HasDiscriminator() and what is it's purpose?

Comment: Is this all of your model? In your code `Select(x => new {x.Id,x.employAddress})` shows that the `x` type object has both an `Id` and `employAddress`, but none of your models have both of those properties. It seems like there is some information missing.

Comment: @jwatts1980 sorry, I've edited the question EmployeeAddressNavigation inherits the Employee. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Here is another SO question that seems to be more related to yours. They added a `[NotMapped]` attribute to the derived class: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6586990/579148

Comment: Infact I did tried that it did not work

Comment: You added it here? `[NotMapped] public class EmployeeAddressNavigation : Employee { }`

Comment: Yes @jwatts1980 sorry for replying I was traveling

Answer (score 0):

When there is inheritance hierarchy in your model you must specify discriminator.Like this

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
            .HasDiscriminator<string>("EmployeeType");
```

To read more about discriminator,see [The Fluent API HasDiscriminator Method](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/hasdiscriminator-method)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please explain What is significance of employeeType here it’s not in my DB table.

Comment: EmployeeType is a column in your Employee table that ef core create to recognize which model inserted in your table.for example when ef core inserts Employee, value of employeeType is "Employee" and when inserts EmployeeAddressNavigation, value of employeeType  is "EmployeeAddressNavigation".

Comment: I do not have column in my sql table called EmployeeType so now I'm getting error invalid column employeetype

Comment: EF added the discriminator implicitly as a shadow property.to read more about , see [Discriminator configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#discriminator-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I thought it was a column named "discriminator" which I dont have. Using **[NotMapped]** on the child worked.

```
[NotMapped]
public class EmployeeAddressNavigation : Employee
{
   public EmpoyeeAddress employAddress {get;set;}
}
```